# How to add build ear file containing only dependency jars in pom

Tags: java, web-applications, maven-2, ear, pom.xml

I would like to create an ear containing only dependency jar files using maven.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>groupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ......
        ......
        ......
    </dependencies>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifcatId</artifactId>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
                ...............
                ...............
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>          
</project>
```

Maven created application.xml automatically which has  entries for these jars but still, when deploying, I am getting message in console - "No modules found in ear."

Could you help me out what am I missing here.

Comment: don't you know CTRL+SHIFT+F ?

Comment: If i'm not wrong an EAR should contain an EJB module and/or and WAR module ?

Answer (score 0):

An EAR file should contain WARs, RARs, SARs, and EJB JARs.  Anything else, including basic library JARs, are unimportant as far as the EAR is concerned and and EAR with just those kind of files is useless as far as a Java EE Application Server is concerned.